# Error while using h264_cuvid decoder with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, cuvid

I am trying to decode a video using the **NVIDIA cuvid** hardware acceleration with **ffmpeg**.

I am using a NVIDIA GeForce GT 745M Graphics card (GPU:GK107), which is compatible with **cuvid** as specified by NVIDIA [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/video-encode-decode-gpu-support-matrix#Encoder)

I compiled ffmpeg with the following flags:

```
./configure --enable-cuda --enable-nvenc --enable-cuvid
```

Then, I used **ffmpeg** with the following command line:

```
ffmpeg.exe -hwaccel cuvid -c:v h264_cuvid -i video.mkv video.mkv
```

**ffmpeg** finishes and seems to be unable to open cuvid functions:

```
Cannot load cuvidGetDecoderCaps
[h264_cuvid @ 07047b80] Failed loading nvcuvid.
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (h264_cuvid) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (ac3 (native) -> vorbis (libvorbis))
  Stream #0:3 -> #0:2 (subrip (srt) -> ass (ssa))
Error while opening decoder for input stream #0:0 : Unknown error occurred
```

In **ffmpeg** source code, I can find out that this error message is printed by the following macro:

```
#define LOAD_SYMBOL(fun, tp, symbol)                                \
    do {                                                            \
        if (!((f->fun) = (tp*)dlsym(f->lib, symbol))) {             \
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot load %s\n", symbol); \
            ret = AVERROR_UNKNOWN;                                  \
            goto error;                                             \
        }                                                           \
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_TRACE, "Loaded sym: %s\n", symbol);     \
    } while (0)
```

Which is called by:

```
static inline int cuvid_load_functions(CuvidFunctions **functions)
{
    GENERIC_LOAD_FUNC_PREAMBLE(CuvidFunctions, cuvid, NVCUVID_LIBNAME);

    LOAD_SYMBOL(cuvidGetDecoderCaps, tcuvidGetDecoderCaps, "cuvidGetDecoderCaps");
    LOAD_SYMBOL(cuvidCreateDecoder, tcuvidCreateDecoder, "cuvidCreateDecoder");
    LOAD_SYMBOL(cuvidDestroyDecoder, tcuvidDestroyDecoder, "cuvidDestroyDecoder");
    LOAD_SYMBOL(cuvidDecodePicture, tcuvidDecodePicture, "cuvidDecodePicture");
#ifdef __CUVID_DEVPTR64
    LOAD_SYMBOL(cuvidMapVideoFrame, tcuvidMapVideoFrame, "cuvidMapVideoFrame64");
    LOAD_SYMBOL(cuvidUnmapVideoFrame, tcuvidUnmapVideoFrame, "cuvidUnmapVideoFrame64");
#else
    LOAD_SYMBOL(cuvidMapVideoFrame, tcuvidMapVideoFrame, "cuvidMapVideoFrame");
    LOAD_SYMBOL(cuvidUnmapVideoFrame, tcuvidUnmapVideoFrame, "cuvidUnmapVideoFrame");
#endif
    LOAD_SYMBOL(cuvidCtxLockCreate, tcuvidCtxLockCreate, "cuvidCtxLockCreate");
    LOAD_SYMBOL(cuvidCtxLockDestroy, tcuvidCtxLockDestroy, "cuvidCtxLockDestroy");
    LOAD_SYMBOL(cuvidCtxLock, tcuvidCtxLock, "cuvidCtxLock");
    LOAD_SYMBOL(cuvidCtxUnlock, tcuvidCtxUnlock, "cuvidCtxUnlock");

    LOAD_SYMBOL(cuvidCreateVideoSource, tcuvidCreateVideoSource, "cuvidCreateVideoSource");
    LOAD_SYMBOL(cuvidCreateVideoSourceW, tcuvidCreateVideoSourceW, "cuvidCreateVideoSourceW");
    LOAD_SYMBOL(cuvidDestroyVideoSource, tcuvidDestroyVideoSource, "cuvidDestroyVideoSource");
    LOAD_SYMBOL(cuvidSetVideoSourceState, tcuvidSetVideoSourceState, "cuvidSetVideoSourceState");
    LOAD_SYMBOL(cuvidGetVideoSourceState, tcuvidGetVideoSourceState, "cuvidGetVideoSourceState");
    LOAD_SYMBOL(cuvidGetSourceVideoFormat, tcuvidGetSourceVideoFormat, "cuvidGetSourceVideoFormat");
    LOAD_SYMBOL(cuvidGetSourceAudioFormat, tcuvidGetSourceAudioFormat, "cuvidGetSourceAudioFormat");
    LOAD_SYMBOL(cuvidCreateVideoParser, tcuvidCreateVideoParser, "cuvidCreateVideoParser");
    LOAD_SYMBOL(cuvidParseVideoData, tcuvidParseVideoData, "cuvidParseVideoData");
    LOAD_SYMBOL(cuvidDestroyVideoParser, tcuvidDestroyVideoParser, "cuvidDestroyVideoParser");

    GENERIC_LOAD_FUNC_FINALE(cuvid);
}
```

Does anybody know if a specific file is needed by **cuvid** to load its functions?
Any clue to what is wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have the problem anymore.

I forgot to use **libnpp** during **ffmpeg** compilation.

My current configuration is :

```
./configure --enable-cuda --enable-nvenc --enable-cuvid --enable-libnpp --extra-cflags=-I<path_to_libnpp_headers> --extra-ldflags=-L<path_to_libnpp_libraries>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you compiled ffmpeg from source with NVIDIA Video Codec SDK following [NVIDIA instructions](https://docs.nvidia.com/video-technologies/video-codec-sdk/12.1/ffmpeg-with-nvidia-gpu/index.html), you need to manually include the associated ld library so your system can find the `.so` shared libraries:

```bash
sudo sh -c "echo '/usr/local/lib' >> /etc/ld.so.conf"
sudo ldconfig
```